# Can't login with Auth::login()

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

I've remembered about login role and I don't know where's a problem.

Here's some code:
config/auth.php

```
return array(

        'driver'       => 'ORM',
        'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
        'hash_key'     => 'hashKey',
        'lifetime'     => 1209600,
        'session_type' => Session::$default,
        'session_key'  => 'auth_user',

        'users' => array(
                // 'admin' => 'b3154acf3a344170077d11bdb5fff31532f679a1919e716a02',
        ),

);
```

// user model

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {

    protected $_has_many = array('roles' =>
        array(
            'model' => 'Role',
            'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
            'through' => 'roles_users',
            )); 
}
```

// register

> $auth = Auth::instance();
>           $user = ORM::factory('user');
>
> ```
>     $user->username = $this->post['email'];
>
>     $user->email    = $this->post['email'];
>
>     $user->password = $auth->hash($this->post['password']);
>
>     $user->type     = 3; // Ordinary user
>     $user->active   = 0; // It will be inactive till he ativates via mail
>
>     try {
>         $user->save();
>     // and so on
> ```

activating

```
    $user = ORM::factory('user', $this->request->param('id'));
    $user->active = 1;
    // login role
    $user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')));
    $user->save();
```

logging in

```
Auth::instance()->login($post['email'], $post['password']);

            if (! Auth::instance()->logged_in()) {
```

And unfortunately logged_in is false. I have no idea why.

I would appriciate any help

Comment: the role 'login' has id 1? can you check manually if the relation between user->role was created?

Comment: Yes, i checked relation. There is proper entry in roles_users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $user->password = $auth->hash($this->post['password']);

Kohana is hashing passwords by it's own. Change this line to:

```
$user->password = $this->post['password'];
```